# How to copy whole column from one datagridview to another?

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, for-loop, datagridview, copy

[image]

There are two datagridview (dgvReport and dgvReport2). dgvReport shows data from server after choosing the fields (which is working fine).

The checkboxes are the name of columns in dgvReport. If a user selects "Email" for example the column and its row data of "Email" should be added to dgvReport2.

My problem is when I select more than one checkbox the output of row is shown only at first column of dgvReport2 not under the appropriate column. For example, in the screenshot the column "fname" data is showing under email column of dgvReport2.

How can I bring the row data under appropriate column?

Below is my coding:

```
'Add dynamic column
Dim newCol As Integer = 0

If chkEmail.Checked = True Then
    Dim column As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    dgvReport2.Columns.Insert(newCol, column)

    With column
        .HeaderText = "email"
        .AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells
        .ReadOnly = True
    End With

    For rows As Integer = 0 To dgvReport.Rows.Count - 1
        For colcnt As Integer = 0 To dgvReport.Columns.Count - 17
            dgvReport2.Rows.Add(dgvReport.Rows(rows).Cells(0).Value)
        Next
    Next

    newCol += 1
End If

If chkFname.Checked = True Then
    Dim column As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    dgvReport2.Columns.Insert(newCol, column)

    With column
        .HeaderText = "fname"
        .AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells
        .ReadOnly = True
    End With

    For rows As Integer = 0 To dgvReport.Rows.Count - 1
        For colcnt As Integer = 0 To dgvReport.Columns.Count - 17
            dgvReport2.Rows.Add(dgvReport.Rows(rows).Cells(1).Value)
        Next
    Next
    newCol += 1
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I find out the answer of my own question. Hope fully it will help others who are looking for same issue:

replace

```
For rows As Integer = 0 To dgvReport.Rows.Count - 1
  For colcnt As Integer = 0 To dgvReport.Columns.Count - 17
    dgvReport2.Rows.Add(dgvReport.Rows(rows).Cells(0).Value)
  Next
Next
```

with the following:

```
        If dgvReport2.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For rows As Integer = 0 To dgvReport.Rows.Count - 1
                dgvReport2.Rows(rows).Cells(newCol).Value =
                dgvReport.Rows(rows).Cells(1).Value
            Next
        Else
            For rows As Integer = 0 To dgvReport.Rows.Count - 1
                dgvReport2.Rows.Add(dgvReport.Rows(rows).Cells(1).Value)
            Next
        End If
```